# Getting Applications from DeviceActivityEvent swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios15

I'm trying to use [DeviceActivityEvent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/deviceactivity/deviceactivityevent#declaration).

```
var comps = DateComponents()
comps.month = 4
let event = DeviceActivityEvent( threshold: comps)
```

Tried above approaches but no good. Any help/tutorial or a sample code would be appreciated.
As it's a newly launched API by Apple, So there's slim to none info provided yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These three frameworks are related,

`Managed Settings`
`Family Controls`
`DeviceActivity`

`Device Activity` is about running our code without launching the app.
`Device Activity Event` are monitors that call extensions when the user reaches the threshold in a `Device Activity Schedule`.

You can get all the help about this from the apple [WWDC2021](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10123/).

Comment: I have followed all steps but in intervalDidStart() of DeviceActivityMonitor class I am not able to restrict the apps / categories.

It's as if MyModel does not have any values set from within MyMonitor. I have confirmed that MyModel does have the correct FamilyActivitySelection apps.